# GitHub collaboration using Android Studio

Tags: java, android, git, android-studio, github

My friends & I are trying to collaborate via `GitHub` on a basic `Android- Studio` project.  I know how to connect our `GitHub` accounts through the website and through `Android- Studio`, that's not the issue.  In other words, we've tested out test comments to commit to see if it goes through, it does successfully.  The changes are reflected on the website when navigating to the appropriate `.java` file (i.e. the test comment).

Which files should & shouldn't be pushed to reduce the chances of errors being thrown at us?  My assumption is, some of the files that are being pushed don't need to be pushed to everyone because it pertains to configurations that's related to their computer.  For example, if someone decides to add a search bar and that person commit/pushed his code, how can I pull that in a way where what he's contributed appears on my machine without running the risk of tampering with my configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Github defaults into a *master* branch (i.e. everytime you commit and push your updated project will be saved into this branch). However, Github enables you to create separate branches, which I believe is the solution you are looking for. If you want to make edits to your project but you are unsure you want to have those edits show in your actual project, create a separate branch and make those edits there. Note that Github enables you to merge branches.